# How to send raw Bluetooth data to BT Keyboard on OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I'm using Logitech's K810 keyboard on OSX. Everything works fine excluding "Fn-lock", which is feature held internally by the device and in order to set it the OS has to communicate with it.

There already [exists solution for Linux](http://www.trial-n-error.de/posts/2012/12/31/logitech-k810-keyboard-configurator/), so the codes that has to be sent are known, but due to the nature of solution it isn't usable on OSX.

The only issue here is HOW to send those known codes to keyboard on OSX. While I can accept library I would rather have utility that would do this (either GUI or CLI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some scraps of information and decided to go with it. I replaced hidraw in original solution with hidapi library and implemented solution using it.

Source code [available on GitHub](https://github.com/exlee/k810_fkeys_mac).

Comment: If anyone has any better idea how to solve it, I'm open to suggestions.